# How to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_{1}$

Tags: real-analysis

As is well known, Stolz–Cesàro theorem is the following:
Let $\displaystyle {(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}}$ and ${\displaystyle (b_{n})_{n\geq 1}}$be two sequences of real numbers. Assume that ${\displaystyle (b_{n})_{n\geq 1}}$ is a strictly monotone and divergent sequence (i.e. strictly increasing and approaching ${\displaystyle +\infty }$ , or strictly decreasing and approaching ${\displaystyle -\infty }$ and the following limit exists:
$${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}}=l.\ }$$
Then, the limit

$${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {a_{n}}{b_{n}}}=l.\ }$$

I want to know that If we have $${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {a_{n}}{b_{n}}}=l.\ }$$ Can we deduce that
$${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}}=l?\ }$$

If so, we can  reslove the following exercise by the above result:

If $a_n\to a, b_n\geq 0, \forall n\in Z^+, \lim_{n\to \infty} b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n=S,$ then
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_{1}=aS.$$

Let $S_n= b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n$ and  $S_0=0$, then $S_n\to S,$ and
$$a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i(S_{n+1-i}-S_{n-i})$$

Hence,

$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_{1}$
$\displaystyle= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i(S_{n+1-i}-S_{n-i})}{n-(n-1)} $

$\displaystyle= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iS_{n+1-i}}{n}=aS.$

If not so, I would appreciate anyone who give the right solution and any suggestions.

Comment: Set $a_n=n+\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ and $b_n=n+\lfloor \frac{n+1}2\rfloor$. Then $a_n/b_n\to 1$, but $(a_{n+1}-a_n)/(b_{n+1}-b_n)$ doesn’t converge. However this site isn’t for homework questions. You might ask at math.stackexchange.com since it’s clear you have put some thought into it.

Comment: This is a standard calculus exercise: split the sum into two parts, $a_1 b_n + \ldots a_k b_{n-k}$ and $a_{k+1} b_{n-k} + \ldots a_n b_1$, choosing $k$ large enough, so that $|a_i - a| < \epsilon$ for $i > k$, and then $n$ large enough, so that $b_n + \ldots b_{n-k+1} < \epsilon$.

Comment: 5 upvotes for an exercise?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks for the counterexample.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  Good idea. I got it.